Spatie PDF Problem with Images in the Header
Please help me with the image in the header for the Spatie/PDF.
I used img tag with the base64 source image but not work.
<img src="data:image/png; base64, {{ public_path('images/logo.png') }}" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
also, I did that:
<img src="data:image/png; base64, {{ file_get_contents(public_path('images/logo.png')) }}" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
but the problem when I use file_get_contents the server freezes and not respond, and I have to restart it.
I used a tag with a background-image style and also same problem.
Please need your help with that.

Not sure how reading from a local file, could make your server "freeze". Guessing it is probably not that part that freezes, but what you intend to do with this afterwards (creating a PDF)? How big (file size) is the image? Also, just reading the file content, will not automagically encode it as base64.

It shows me This site can’t be reached and every page will not work. and I have to restart the server (stop and rewrite php artisan serve) .. Image size 60kb, File size 250kb

Problem is that you try to put in the path to file or file content, not the base64 conent to it.
Try this:
<img src="data:image/png; base64, {{ base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path('images/logo.png'))) }}" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">


I tried file_get_contents as I said but everything stopped after that and showed me this:
This site can’t be reached
every page will not open and I have to restart the server (stop and rewrite php artisan serve)
